# From whom should I get an OTRS ticket for a work if the copyright holder is deceased?

Tags: wikimedia-commons

I have uploaded a non-free work to Wikimedia Commons whose copyright holder is deceased. From should I get the OTRS ticket?

Answer (score 1):

The copyright holder's heirs, unless some other arrangement was made.